# Property "Centroid" of result from ConvexHullMesh[] can not be extracted

Tags: computational-geometry, undocumented, properties, version-12.2

As the title describes, specifically, simple code below

```
ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]]["Centroid"]
```

returns an error in V. 12.2, but it worked in V. 12.1.1 as far as I remember

> ```
> BoundaryMeshRegion::unsupported
> ```

Is it a bug introduced by the new version? Or is there another way to get the centroid?

---

**Update**

I just find it that not only `"Centroid"`, but also extractions of other `"Properites"` fail; except for `"BoundaryPolygons"`.

---

**Update 2**

To make this problem more understandable, let me make some modifications to the code.

```
mesh = ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]];
mesh["Properties"]
```

This would return a long `List` of strings as the properties `mesh` has. And then

```
mesh[str]
```

would return something, at least without any error message, where `str` is arbitrary one of the elements of the aforementioned property `List`; very much like OOP (objective-oriented programming). And that is what would happen in former versions like V. 12.1.1.

However now in V. 12.2, `mesh["Centroid"]` fails, even though `"Centroid"` can be found in that property `List` of `mesh`.

Comment: `RegionCentroid[ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]]]` ?

Comment: @cvgmt Thx very much, it works for the data extraction. But it only solves half of the problem. I doubt that something is wrong with `BoundaryMeshRegion` in the new version, isn't it?

Comment: `MeshPrimitives@ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]]` ? What is the `"Properites"` ？

Comment: @cvgmt Plz see my Update 2.

Comment: Perhaps we need to be reminded that these properties are actually *undocumented* stuff, so there is no guarantee that they should still work in future versions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Accessing properties of BoundaryMeshRegion that way was undocumented and therefore might not work anymore in 12.2.

A somewhat documented way is the `AnnotationValue` approach. Eg.

```
AnnotationValue[{ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]], 1}, MeshCellMeasure]
```

But this doesn't work for all properties either (also see Possible Issues section). In that case **Centroid** is not working.

What is still working is this also undocumented approach:

```
mesh = Graphics`Region`ToMeshObject[ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]]];
mesh["Centroid"]
```